# Contact Information on community Home tab

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-service-cloud, salesforce-chatter

I have created a community and its landing tab is home tab.It only consist of home tab.I need to display the contact information on this home tab.
Can anyone help me with this? I also need to activate chatter for this community.How do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used home tab for chatter using custom link and components.I have used VF page to display contact information.